# Root test for convergence: $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty} (a+bi)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a+bi)^n$$ where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

I'm having trouble with this question. I get to $a+bi$ but I have no clue how to finish it in order to determine if it converges absolutely or not.

Comment: It seems like there isn't enough context here to do anything substantial. As far as I know, the root test for convergence is used to determine if a series is convergent. Here it looks like we have a sequence instead to deal with. Furthermore, are $a$ and $b$ already given?

Comment: @Scounged The series is S(a,b) = ∑ n=0 ∞ (a+bi)^n. 'a' and 'b' are not given. Different values of 'a' and 'b' are substituted to create a complex plane to determine convergence.

Comment: Ok. So instead of writing $a+bi$, I guess we could just write it as a complex number $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question:

Let $z=a+bi\in\mathbb{C}$. We want to determine where in the complex plane the series $$S(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$$

converges. Using the root test:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|z^n|}=|z|$$

we see that the sum absolutely converges if $|z|=|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}<1$, and the sum diverges if $|z|>1$. Thus the radius of convergence for the series is $R=1$.

We can also note that for $|z|<1$, we have that $S(z)$ is a geometric series with the quotient $z$, which gives us that 
$$S(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-z}$$

which reinforces the idea that the radius of convergence is $R=1$, as the right hand side in the equation above has a pole in $z=1$, and nowhere else.

Furthermore, if we are interested in the **sequence**, we get that the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}z^n$ exists if either $|z|<1$ or $z=1$. In the first case we get that the limit is zero, and in the second, we get the trivial limit one.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how in the first part you came to a conclusion of R=1 from the sqrt(a^2+b^2).

Comment: It has to do with how the root test works: 
If we have a sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, and the limit $Q=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ exists, the root test says that:
If $Q<1$, the series converges absolutely. If $Q>1$, the series diverges.
In our case we had immediately that $Q=|z|$, and the definition of the absolute value of a complex number $z=a+bi$ is $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. The radius of convergence then comes from the upper limit of $|z|$ where the series still converges.

Comment: I understand that bit. But how does the sqrt(a^2+b^2)=1?

Comment: Ok. $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ isn't equal to one just because the radius of convergence is one. Think of it instead like: "The radius of convergence is $R=1$. This means that if $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}<1$, the series will converge, and if $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}>1$, the series will diverge."

Comment: The radius of convergence is defined as the number $R>0$ that fulfills the following two conditions: 

$|z|<R\Rightarrow$ The series converges.
$|z|>R\Rightarrow$ The series diverges.

In the given series, the number $R=1$ is the number which fulfills these conditions.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: write $z=a+ib$ as $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ where $\rho,\theta$ are polar coordinates.

So $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}(a+ib)^n=\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\rho^ne^{in\theta}$$